# the parameters changing of w element interconnect model for various technologies in hspice?

Tags: hspice

how can I change the parameters of w element interconnect for various technologies, for example, 90, 64, and 180nm technologies in hspice? I attach one code in the attached picture from hspice tutorial pdf.[image]

Comment: What does a transmission line have to do with MOS (I presume) technology? Could you clarify your question a bit?

Comment: Transmission line effects of ESL, M, Crosstalk C , Ciss, Coss Rs and skin effects has everything to do transmission line theory and Maxwellian Theory from capacitance.